# Java Round decimal - specific case second decimal Zero

Tags: java, rounding

Given this numbers:

- 150.00
- 150.26

I need to round like this:

- If the second value of decimal part is zero (0), then the new value should be 150.0
- If the second value of decimal part is different than zero (0), then the new value keeps both decimals Ex.: 150.26

Is there a rounding method that can do this?

Thanks.

My code here:

```
String monto = "150.10";//150.26
String nuevoMonto = "";
String[] valores = monto.split("\\.");
System.out.println("Valores : " + valores);
System.out.println("Valores length: " + valores.length);
for (int i = 0; i < valores.length; i++) {
  System.out.println("-->Valor: " + valores[i]);
}
if (valores.length == 2) {
  nuevoMonto = valores[1];
  System.out.println("Nuevomonto: " + nuevoMonto);
  if (nuevoMonto.length() == 2) {
    System.out.println("Dos posiciones decimales");
    System.out.println(nuevoMonto.indexOf("0"));
    if (nuevoMonto.indexOf("0") == 1) {
      nuevoMonto = valores[0] + "." + nuevoMonto.substring(0, 1);
    }
  }

}

System.out.println("Nuevo monto: " + nuevoMonto);
```

Comment: Hard to know what you really want, also please show what you've tried so far. If you are working with money, this might be a pretty arbitrary way to round values. `150.10 -> 150.10 ... 150.09 -> 150.00` would be a quite big difference. So WHY do you want to round this way?

Comment: @hamena314 he said **second** value of decimal part... So 150.10 -> 150.1 and 150.09 -> 150.09

Comment: What about 150.101? Or maybe that "cannot happen"?

Comment: I think that this is more related to formatting than rounding.

Comment: This isn't rounding, it's just omitting trailing zeroes, which is the default for `Float.toString` and `Double.toString` already.

Comment: I agree with yout, this is more related with formatting. I just upload my code. But @JornVernee answer solved my question. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

try something like this:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.0#");
System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(150.09));
System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(150.10));
```

The string inside the new decimal format allows `#`s to be trimmed, and `0`s are forced to stay

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string to start with, perhaps there is no point parsing it to a floating point number and then reformatting it. Another approach is to use a regexp for this:

```
String monto = "150.10";
String nuevoMonto = monto.replaceAll("(?<=\\.\\d)0$", "")
```

The regexp consist of two parts. The first part `(?<=\\.\\d)` says the match need to be preceded by a dot and a digit. The second part `0$` matches the trailing zero at the end of the string. We replace it with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

There is an expression in Java called floor method which can be used to always bring a value with any form of rounding to an integer value with any relevant decimal points removed from the data
a simple check for this wold be to take the data and check if the data is not modulo or mod of a zero 
sample code might look like this.

```
if ((monto % 0.1 ) == 0)
{
   //has no relevant data so it should be floored
   Nuevomonto = floor (monto);
}
else 
{
Nuevomonto = monto;
}
```

hope that helps.